# Trying to make a menu on the bottom without using showasaction

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-menu

If I don't use show as action=always when creating a menu will it create a menu on the bottom like the old school android phones. I'm trying to create something that has like the facebook mobile tabs on the bottom, and has them for every screen. Or should I actually just make tabs for every screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in a "split action bar". That way your items could appear at the bottom.  showAsAction controls how/if the item appear in the Action Bar.

More information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar

If that doesn't look of interest then yes.. you should use tabs (or a view of some sort) at the bottom to render your "menu items".